# Are emulators good enough for testing websites on mobile browsers?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, unit-tests, cross-browser-testing

I have made a website. I visited the same website on different mobile browsers and getting some UI error and a button is not working correctly. How can I test my website to get over from this problem??